# How to handle redirects in axios and spring controller?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, react-redux

I am trying to create cart in my web application in which redirection is done in spring controller based on the product is added, updated etc. I wrote axios get request that call     `@RequestMapping("/add/{productId}/product")` which redirect to another request mapping and result is return. I am putting result in map and i can see map result on console. But i am not able to get result in redux store.

this is redirected link `show?result=updated`. which throwing 404 error.

this is my `axios` get request.

```
export const getCart = (pt_id) => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/cart/add/${pt_id}/product`);
  
  dispatch({
    type: GET_CART,
    payload: res.data
  });
};
```

In spring controller

```
@RequestMapping("/{cartLineId}/update")
public String udpateCartLine(@PathVariable int cartLineId, @RequestParam int count) {
    String response = cartService.manageCartLine(cartLineId, count);        
    return "redirect:/cart/show?"+response;     
}

@RequestMapping("/add/{productId}/product")
public String addCartLine(@PathVariable int productId) {
    String response = cartService.addCartLine(productId);
    return "redirect:/cart/show?"+response;
}


@RequestMapping("/show")
public Map<String, Object> showCart(@RequestParam(name = "result", required = false) String result) {
    
    Map<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    cartMap.put("title", "Shopping Cart");
    
    if(result!=null) {
        switch(result) {
            
            case "added":
                cartMap.put("message", "Product has been successfully added inside cart!");
                cartService.validateCartLine();
                break;

            case "unavailable":
                cartMap.put("message", "Product quantity is not available!");
                break;
            
            case "updated":
                cartMap.put("message", "Cart has been updated successfully!");
                cartService.validateCartLine();
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        String response = cartService.validateCartLine();
        if(response.equals("result=modified")) {
            cartMap.put("message", "One or more items inside cart has been modified!");
        }
    }

    cartMap.put("cartLines", cartService.getCartLines());
    return cartMap; 
}
```

if i print cartMap i can see result on console.

this is Network log

**general**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/cart/show?result=updated
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 404
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=431DE0256413C4B665CFC94601E6DB9C; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 05 Feb 2019 05:42:22 GMT
```

**Request**

```
GET /cart/show?result=updated HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:3000/cart/add/28/product
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm experiencing similar troubles with Spring Security's formLogin redirect after successful login.